# Make permission bypass for Ajax requests from my website in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I made this API permission

```py
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    return request.user.is_authenticated and (
       request.user.is_superuser or
       models.AllowedToUseAPIList.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists()
)
```

where I check if user who asks for API is added into list of `AllowedToUseAPIList`.
But I also need to make AJAX requests from other pages of this website to this API. *How can I change the permission to allow doing that?*
I also pass my CSRF token into AJAX call but get 403.

I make Ajax call like that:

```js
let csrf = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
...
$.ajax({
    url:"{% url 'api:ajax_api:save-mark' %}",
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf,
        "name": that.name,
        "value": value,
        },
    success: function (data){
        ...
    }
})
```

After all, I get 403 Permission Denied.

Comment: Can you please share your ajax request and the erorr itself?

Comment: @Daniel see edit

Comment: is there an issue with the csrf token - is that passed correctly? i.e. does the error say missing or incorrect csrf token?

Comment: @Daniel yep, it's correct. The question is not about passing csrf - it's about making my permission bypass Ajax call but stay true for any other user.

Comment: Not sure I understand still - but below is one method to bypass the csrf token.

Comment: @Daniel , I want to make my API available ONLY to users mentioned in model ``AllowedToUseAPIList`` but bypass this rule with Ajax calls.

Comment: I think I understand now - how about the edited solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a parameter that tells the view when a bypass is allowed:

js:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"{% url 'api:ajax_api:save-mark' %}",
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf,
        "name": that.name,
        "value": value,
        "bypass" : true, // add this parameter
        },
    success: function (data){
        ...
    }
})
```

python:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):

    # check if request was triggered by ajax:
    ajax_bypass = 'bypass' in request.POST and request.POST['bypass']

    # check if use is a superuser:
    user_is_superuser = request.user.is_superuser

    # check if user is in allowed list:
    user_is_authorized = models.AllowedToUseAPIList.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists()

    return ajax_bypass or user_is_superuser or user_is_authorized
```

Comment: I think it's OK but I got the best solution - just to turn off browsable API